# How do you change the title of an edge browser tab with selenium & vba

Tags: microsoft-edge

I cant figure out how to change the title or name shown at the top of the browser tab with Selenium & vba.  Browser is Edge chromium.  Using the stack overflow site as an example... If I wanted to change the text at the top of a tab from "Stack Overflow" to "My favorite website ever!", I can go into the devtools console and and type document.title = "My favorite website ever!"

I do some automation through excel \vba & selenium and have a couple tabs that all have the same title.  When I start my script and open the tabs, I'd like to be able to give each one a unique name.

Everything I find while researching is about getting the title as it is currently displayed or how to loop through tabs to find the one you want.  Have not found anything besides the method in devtools or through a browser extension that actually changes what is displayed.

Here is some sample code...

```
    Set D = New EdgeDriver        

        With D
            .Start "Edge"
            .Window.SetSize 1130, 960
            .Window.SetPosition 400, 0
            .Get HubURL
            .FindElementByCss("a:nth-child(4)").Click 'KINSTON PAGE
            .Wait (2000)

            Do While .Url <> KinstonURL
                .SwitchToNextWindow
                Loop
            
            .Wait (1000)
            
            .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/_div/div/div/ _ 
            div/div/div[2]/h3/span[1]", timeout:=30000).Click 'SHOW ALL
            
            .Wait (2000)

            .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemsPanel']/div[2]/menu- _ 
            .item[1]item[1]/div/img", timeout:=20000).Click 'ALERT INBOX
        
            '***===Here is the line I added per the first answer below===***
            D.ExecuteScript ("document.title = Kinston MES Inbox")
       End With


Here is the runtime error it gives me:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgqOy.jpg
```

Comment: Hi, just to check. Have you tried the modification in my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straightforward: tell the WebDriver to execute JavaScript.

```
driver.ExecuteScript ("document.title = 'My favorite website ever!'")
```

Comment: I added a bit of my sample code to the original post,

Using the method you recommended gives me this runtime error 17

Comment: @JohnRitchey You forgot to include Kinston MES Inbox inside single quotation marks. Try `D.ExecuteScript ("document.title = 'Kinston MES Inbox'")`